# Freehub comes free from wheel with cassette attached

Tags: freehub

I was cleaning my bike and a gust of wind knocked my wheel over which had been standing up against a wall. I found the cassette/freehub detached from the wheel. The end caps don't appear to have a thread and I wonder if this is okay, as everything would be held in place when the wheel is placed on the bike. Could someone confirm?

For reference, the wheel is a Reynolds AR62.

I've uploaded a demonstrative video to Imgur, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrcTM.jpg)

Comment: It's a normal design for some hubs. The powertap hub does this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually can't remove the freehub body on most hubs by hand, as is probably obvious. However, on at least some hubs, the freehub body does slide right off. [Mountain Bike Rider](https://www.mbr.co.uk/news/service-dt-swiss-freehub-361886) mentions this about DT Swiss star ratchet hubs in general, and I am able to do this on a DT Swiss 370 hub (a lower-end hub with pawls). Consider that while you are riding, the hub is under some compressive force from the thru axle or quick release. The freehub should be unable to just back off out of the hub.

Comment: That's.... terrifying.

Comment: I can confirm this can happen with DT Swiss 350 hubs. The freehub body is held in by a "top hat" axle adaptor, which is held on by friction. Per Weiwen Ng's point, it can't happen when it's on the bike - the "top hat" is captured by the dropouts and can't move.

Comment: @Criggie Awww, not really.  By the time the freehub falls out of your wheel, you're already well past the, "Ummm, this is gonna end badly..." part of your ride. So the marginal terror added is zero. :-)